# Replace Repeating of string with digit after decimal of two digit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using datatables, After clicking of pagination button sum is appending.. 
Help Appreciated. Thanks in advance
Whenever I click the button same digit are appending. as already present. I want for example, if it's 23.2323.23, want to keep 23.23 and remove after that

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  $("label").text($("label").text().replace(/[0-9]{2}\.[0-9][0-9]$/g, ''));
  $("label").append("55")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Total amount:23.2323.233</label>
<button id=btn>Click</button>
```

Comment: What string are you referring?

Comment: what is this string and why do you want to remove it?

Comment: Quite confusing, you always append “55” every time you clicked the button.  What exactly you want to replace? Is it the number of decimal or what string you referring?

Comment: Removed the “55” and replace it of your variable sum so it will update. Or to make it more clear place your whole code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at your try first.
You used `/[0-9]{2}\.[0-9][0-9]$/g` for searching the pattern.
it means two digits followed by dot followed by two digit (`$` means it should end with it. for example, 23.23 ) which is certainly not the pattern you are looking for.

The pattern you are looking for is digits.digits.digits.digits ...

if you express it with regular expression, digits(.digits)+, it leads to `/[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+`

So the final code should be:

```
$("label").text($("label").text().replace(/[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+/g, ''));
```

**Edit:**

```
$("label").text($("label").text().replace(/[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+/g, $("label").text().match(/([0-9]+)\.[0-9]{2}/)[0]));
```

Comment: I tried this and its working but issue is: it removing digit before decimal. Like 1250.33  willbe going to 1250

Comment: if you don't want to remove digit before decimal, it's easy. just use `/(\.[0-9]+)+/g` then

Comment: i want to remove all digit after 2 digit of decimal

Comment: for example, if it's 23.2323.23, you want to keep 23.23 and remove after that?

Comment: please added `edit` paragraph in my answer. please check if it works for you.

Comment: in my opinion, if you remove all before appending from the first time, this issue will never happen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190023/discussion-between-aishwarya-and-undefined).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
parseFloat('23.2323.233').toFixed(2)
```

Comment: This wouldn't remove the string but turn it to `23.23`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to completely remove the previous numeric value shown in the label before appending a new value.

So you want to keep `Total amount:` only. Then append the value you obtained from DataTable after pagination...

What about the [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method then?
it create an array based on a "sepearator".

In your case, I would use the `:` character and keep the first array item.
Notice that you have to re-add the `:`...

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  var value_from_DT = 55.72;
  $("label").text($("label").text().split(":")[0]+":");
  $("label").append(value_from_DT)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Total amount:23.23</label>
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Another way, **that would be best**, would be to have a dedicated `span` specifically for the numeric value:

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  var value_from_DT = 55.72;
  $("#DT_sum").text(value_from_DT);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Total amount:<span id="DT_sum">23.23</span></label>
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

(I am not much clear about your question.) 
if you want to remove the string from the label do this

```
$("label").empty().append("55")
```